# Trouble with ARC releasing prematurely or not at all

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, avfoundation

I have a simple little music player written to use AVFoundation under 10.8. It works great, but I was only recently introduced to ARC, which is giving me some trouble.

The application is document-based, with the bulk of necessary code living in the premade Document.h/.m files. There is a __strong AVAudioPlayer object defined in the header which all the functions in the implementation make use of to play audio files. Files are loaded with the standard readFromURL: method.

When closing documents, the files do not get released and even continue playing. If the AVAudioPlayer is set to weak, it get released almost immediately and files will no longer play.

Is there something I'm missing here? I know I can't release manually under ARC, so what could be keeping the object tied up?

Comment: People should really not use ARC at all.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe that wouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: H2CO3, your opinion, while perfectly valid for yourself, should not be a blanket recommendation.  ARC is exactly where the entire system is heading, the tools are optimized for ARC, the compiler is much better under ARC, and ARC is being adopted across many projects at Apple exactly because it produces more stable software with less maintenance issues.  In this case, it sounds like OP needs to explicitly *stop* playback of the audio, which should be decoupled from memory management anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object pointers in ARC are strong by default. Any reference you have to your `AVAudioPlayer` that isn't defined to be weak and is in an object/class that's still around will keep it from being deallocated. If your files keep playing, it's probably not an ARC problem, but something you're doing with `AVAudioPlayer`.

A way to "release" memory in ARC is to set the pointer to an object to `nil`. If there are no other references to the object, it will be deallocated.

Comment: Thanks, setting the player to nil under windowWillClose works nicely. I'll see if I can figure out what's keeping it around anyway, though.